# using mongoengine with models.ImageField

Tags: django, amazon-s3, mongoengine

I'm having trouble getting a django/mongoengine app to use [django-athumb](https://github.com/duointeractive/django-athumb). I'm trying to save different sizes of images and store them on S3, which is exactly what athumbs does when used with a stock django install. However, with mongoengine, calling save() on the object's field results in a "*'ImageWithThumbsField' object has no attribute 'save'*" message.

inside the views function that deals with the file upload (where doc.image is a *ImageWithThumbsField*):

```
if request.FILES.get('image'):
    file = request.FILES['image']
    fdat = file.read()
    file_contents = ContentFile(fdat)
    doc.image.save(file.name, file_contents)
```

the above results in the aforementioned error.

if I instead call:

```
doc.image.attr_class(file_contents, doc.image, file.name).save(file.name, file_contents)
```

I am able to access the save method, but it's hackish and may cause more problems then it solves.  My question: since *ImageWithThumbsField* subclasses *models.ImageField*, is it impossible (or at least impractical) to use *models.ImageField* with mongoengine?

Answer (score 1):

I know this question is old, but it seems at the time there was no support for [ImageField in mongoengine - this was added in version 0.6.](http://mongoengine-odm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/apireference.html#mongoengine.ImageField)

If you still have an issue with mongoengine, please try upgrading to a version greater than 0.6 .. they even throwed in the ability to generate a thumbnail